# Can SharePoint 2013 workflow emailing an Office 365 group?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-email, office-365-groups

I've create a SharePoint 2013 list workflow and I need to send an email. However I didn't want to send it to one person. People frequently come and go.

As Office 365 groups have an email address, I thought perhaps I could use this email address.

Can someone advise me if this is possible, and how please?

I've attempted to put the email address directly in the "To" of send email, but this errors, as the workflow is trying to resolve the email address as an user.